# How to synchronize calctab package total for exam class question points

Tags: exam

I use the `exam` class to create my exams. Furthermore, I use the `calctab` package to provide a detailed explanation about the achievable points. The table provides the possibility to sum the points. Now, I would like to use the `calctab` total as the question points for an `exam` class question. Ideally, the total synchronizes the question points. Any hints how to achieve this kind of automatic behavior?

Here is an example:

```latex
\documentclass[addpoints, answers]{exam}
\usepackage{calctab}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}   

\question[2]

Task Description

\begin{solution}

Solution

\ctcurrency{Points}
\ctdescription{Criteria}
\begin{calctab}
\amount{Foo}{1}
\amount{Bar}{1}
\add{Total}
\end{calctab}

\end{solution}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome. I hope it is fixed now.